# OpenXml excel pivot table hide column subtotal

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I have created pivot table in excel using open xml sdk.Now I want to hide subtotals at column level.How can I achieve this through c# code? Can anyone help?

Thanks & Regards,
Surbhi